# Google spreadsheet change a cell depending on what is written on another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In a cell I have a list of locations made with data validation. Example Budapest, Belgrade, Bucharest.
next to the cell I have formula that i have to change manually if i change the cell with the location, EX: `=index( Budapest!I:I; max(if(Budapest!B:B=E127; row(Budapest!B:B)))), =index( Belgrade!I:I; max(if(Belgrade!B:B=E127; row(Belgrade!B:B))))`...etc

Is it a way to change automatically the formula, for ex if I select the city Budapest the formula to change to Budapest.

I have tried: `=if(F127="Budapest"index( Budapest!I:I; max(if(Budapest!B:B=E127; row(Budapest!B:B))))) if(f127="Belgrade"index(Belgrade!F:F; max(if(Belgrade!B:B=E127; row(Belgrade!B:B)))))`

Comment: You'll need to look into forming references using the `INDIRECT` function (e.g., `INDIRECT(F127&"!I:I")` in place of `Budapest!I:I`. However, understand that using `INDIRECT` means that all sheet ranges (e.g., the `I:I` part) become an inflexible part of a string. So if you later adjust sheets by inserting a columns such that `I:I` becomes `J:J`, for instance, those `INDIRECT` strings will need to be manually updated (or updated via Find/Replace). There are ways to write the flexibility in, but they are complex; and without seeing your sheet or data, I can't suggest anything further.

Answer (score 1):

if A1 = Bucharest (or whatever else) use:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(A1&"!I:I"); MAX(IF(INDIRECT(A1&"!B:B")=E127; ROW(INDIRECT(A1&"!B:B")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on where the input data is will determine what the best formula to use it. But to be vague, the answer is yes. It will most likely require you to use a formula that pulls data and instead of the putting in a location of where to pull from, put a cell reference. Some formulas wont let you use a cell’s contents to reference a location. In that case you can concatenate the string from a cell into the formula. Here is an example of concatenation within a formula that does not allow cell references (query select where).

`=QUERY('tab1'!$A$4:$R, "select * where A = '"&$C$5&"'")`

It pulls all data where column A matches whatever value is typed into cell C5.

I understand this formula does not match your data but it provides an explanation of the mechanism of how to do so. I hope it helps. If not, please provide an example sheet and I can create a specific formula for your situation.

Comment: Ok, this is a copy of what I work with : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1U_KoebXQaXkW5O54ImhkSRWtotqSFU3YG5WPzGw4StI/edit?usp=sharing  , as you can see there are 4 sheets with cities, each city has some cars attributed, I want the information to change if the car is available, where it is and so on, this I manage so far, but I want to find a simple way to change the car from one city to another without having to change the formula, and without data validation. I hope I made myself clear, is a bit hard to explain it

Comment: @OvidiuStefanPirvu Your example sheet is very hard to understand and is not my language. Can you give a general objective for the whole sheet? Are you trying to organize and coordinate the locations of vehicles between 4 cities?